# Join from custom table to customer_entity table and get all data customer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sql, join-table

I used this code but it not working. Please help me!

```
$customerEntity = $locationList->getTable('customer_entity');

$locationList = $this->mpSellerMapLocatorModel->getCollection();
$locationList->getSelect()->join(
            $customerEntity.' as cpev',
            'main_table.seller_id = cpev.entity_id',
            ['firstname','lastname']
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution:

> ```
>     $locationList->getSelect()
>     ->join(array('cpev' => 'customer_entity'), 
>     'cpev.entity_id=main_table.seller_id', 
> array('firstname' => 'firstname', 'lastname' => 'lastname'));
> ```

Also donot call the collection using model class using `$locationList = $this->mpSellerMapLocatorModel->getCollection();`

Use Collection Class means `{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/Model/ResourceModel/{Entity}/Collection`

Comment: thanks you very much! can you help me this issue? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277547/how-to-get-data-from-custom-table-by-entity-id-for-custom-table-in-magento-2