# How to get data from custom table by entity_id for custom table in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Table custom like this

[image]

I want get data from table " custom " by id in block magento 2. Please help me! Thanks all

**UPDATE**

I want get data by " custom_id "

[image]

**UPDATE**

function __construct

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Webkul\MpSellerMapLocator\Model\Mpsellermaplocator $mpSellerMapLocatorModel,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->mpSellerMapLocatorModel = $mpSellerMapLocatorModel;
}
```

get data

```
$customId = 4;
$marketplaceMpsellermaplocator = $this->mpSellerMapLocatorModel->addFieldToFilter('custom_id', $customId);
echo "<pre>";var_dump($marketplaceMpsellermaplocator->getData());
exit;
```

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html this can help you.

Comment: Name field coming from join or name is the field of your custom table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use load by Id to get data by id.

Try with below way.

Add below code in your block file.

```
<?php
namespace Test\Module\Block;

class TestBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

  protected $customTable;  


  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Namespace\ModuleName\Model\customTableFactory $customTable

    ) {


        $this->customTable = $customTable;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->customTable->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```

In the above code, I inject class `\Namespace\ModuleName\Model\customTableFactory` in your case you have to inject your model class. and pass your `entity_id` in `$id`

That's it! I hope it helps.

---

**Update:**

**You can also get data by another field like below.**

```
protected $customTablecollection;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Webkul\MpSellerMapLocator\Model\ResourceModel\Mpsellermaplocator\collection $mpSellerMapLocatorModel,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->mpSellerMapLocatorModel = $mpSellerMapLocatorModel;
}
```

And then you can use your variable directly in your code:

```
$customId = 4;
$marketplaceMpsellermaplocator = $this->mpSellerMapLocatorModel->addFieldToFilter('custom_id', $customId);
echo "<pre>";var_dump($marketplaceMpsellermaplocator->getData());
exit;
```

Comment: can you get it by name ?

Comment: Yes you can get it by name also but you have to use another methode.

Comment: can you help me ? :(((

Comment: Check my updated answer :)

Comment: Hi Chirag Patel! You are right, thank you. can you check update question? i have a new issue, get data by custom_id

Comment: pass `custom_id` like `$messages = $this->customTablecollection->addFieldToFilter('custom_id', $customId);`

Comment: it not working Chirag Patel! please check update question again

Comment: It is not working because of you have not used `collection method` check my update answer and try.

Comment: Thank you very much <3 Chirag Patel

Comment: You are welcome +1 for nice question. :)